# Using random numbers from a range of -10 to 10, I want to write a program that will change the places of two columns

Tags: python

Using random numbers from a range of -10 to 10, I want to write a program that will change the places of two columns. A column that contains the maximum negative element, and a column that contains the minimum positive element of the matrix.Lets say the numbers are randomly generated so there can be no 10 or -10 for example lets say for the rows of maximum negative value lets say we have a range of -8 -2 3 5 so the maximum negative value here is -2 so the rows will change to -2 -8 3 5 and for the minimum postive value lets say a range of -4 -2 3 6 8 the number here is 3 so the range will change to 3 -4 -2 6 8 Here is the code that I am working on and this is how far I was able to go but I dont understand how I can introduce the max negative and min positive number.

```
import random
print("Enter number of cols:")
n = int(input())
print("Enter number of rows:")
m = int(input())

rows, cols = (m, n)
nums=[]
for i in range(rows):
    col = []
    for j in range(cols):
        col.append(random.randint(-10, 10))
    nums.append(col)

for row in nums:
    print(row)

updatedNums = []
```

Comment: I'd say just use the corresponding range, generate a list and use `min()` and `max()` to extract a single number. e.g. `max_negative = max([random.randint(-10, 0) for i in range(5)])`. Here 0 can be a result since th upper bound is included. If you want to exclude it, just use `(-10, -1)` as range.

Comment: The goal you're trying to unchieve appears to me really really unclear. I'm not sure I understand the desired output, could you clarify ?

Comment: @MaximeBouhadana I want to create a code where it takes the highest negative value and puts it in the first position in my matrix with the other numbers and the same with the smallest positive number. I want to make to rows with random numbers generated s for example we have a range -8 -5 -3 2 5 7 first row to find the biggest negative number and put it in the first position so the updated matrix to look like this [-3 -8 -5 2 5 7] and the same thing with the positive one for example--8 -5 -2 2 5 7 so the updated is [2 -8 -5 -2 5 7] did I make it clear or harder to explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from random import randint

ncols = int(input('Number of columns: '))
nrows = int(input('Number of rows: '))

data = [[randint(-10, 10) for _ in range(ncols)] for _ in range(nrows)]

for r in data:
    print('Original: ', r)
    maxneg = max(n for n in r if n < 0)
    r.insert(0, r.pop(r.index(maxneg)))
    print('Max -ve moved: ', r)
    minpos = min(n for n in r if n > 0)
    r.insert(0, r.pop(r.index(minpos)))
    print('Min +ve moved: ', r)
```